# pngquant doesn't work with php

Tags: php, linux, pngquant

I have installed pngquant on a mac and on a linux running centos 7. On both machines I can use it with command line, but if won't work when the same command is run in php.

Linux commands I tried:

```
yum install pngquant
```

says it succesfully installed pngquant

```
which pngquant
```

returns `/usr/bin/pngquant`

my php file code ptst.php:

```
<?php
echo "start";
 echo $get_compress = exec("find . -name '*.png' -exec /usr/bin/pngquant -ext .png -force 256 {} \;");
echo "end";
?>
```

I only have 1 png file in current folder: `image_5.png`. It has permissions: `-rwxrwxrw-`, and is in the same folder as `ptst.php`

upon using `ls -la` I can see that the file size hasn't changed. The echoed outout is just `startend`.

If I run the same code in Terminal, the file size changes to 1/3 of it's previous size.

What am I doing wrong? There is clearly some issues I don't know about.

EDIT:
new command:

```
echo $get_compress = exec("find . -name '*.png' -exec /usr/bin/pngquant --ext .png --force 256 {} \; 2>&1", $output);
print_r($output);
```

output is a bit more illustrative;

```
'./image_5.png.tmp' for writingArray ( [0] => error: cannot open './image_5.png.tmp' for writing )
```

Answer (score 0):

use `sudo` and it'll work. Worked for me.

Comment: How should people do that? Please elaborate